# Decimal rounding error: numpy floor and trunc not working correctly in python when used on pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rounding-error

I am getting some strange behavior with np.floor and np.trunc when I am using pandas dataframes.

This is the behavior I expect, which is working:

```
np.floor(30.000)
Out[133]: 30.0
```

But you can see that when I do a series it treats "floating integers" wrong, and rounds them down by one. I used a temporary fix of adding 0.00001 to my entire dataframe, which in my case is okay because of the level I am rounding to, but I would like to know what is happening and how to do it correctly.

Edit: I specifically need the round down to zero feature.

sample_series

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00    26.750
2020-01-01 01:00:00    27.500
2020-01-01 02:00:00    28.250
2020-01-01 03:00:00    30.000
2020-01-01 04:00:00    30.625
2020-01-01 05:00:00    31.000
2020-01-01 06:00:00    33.375
2020-01-01 07:00:00    33.750
2020-01-01 08:00:00    34.000

In: sample_series.apply(np.float)
Out:

2020-01-01 00:00:00    26.0
2020-01-01 01:00:00    27.0
2020-01-01 02:00:00    28.0
2020-01-01 03:00:00    29.0
2020-01-01 04:00:00    30.0
2020-01-01 05:00:00    30.0
2020-01-01 06:00:00    33.0
2020-01-01 07:00:00    33.0
2020-01-01 08:00:00    33.0
2020-01-01 09:00:00    33.0
2020-01-01 10:00:00    34.0
```

Comment: with float you can't always trust what pandas displays; there can be a discrepancy between the underlying number and what shows on the screen. For instance, pandas will store the number `pd.Series([29.99999999999999])`, yet the display is `30.0`. So then when you `floor` it goes to 29 because it's based on the underlying data, not the formatted display. I suggest you look at stuff like `df.loc[whatever_date]` to see exactly what number you have.

Comment: Thank you for that. I looked into it already and if that is the problem it is hard to see. The number seems to round to exactly 30, as it is the average of these numbers*1000

[`0.028,
0.027,
0.02,
0.029,
0.033,
0.033,
0.034,
0.036],` but it guess there could be a floating point rounding error I can't see there.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `around()` function

```
np.around([0.37, 1.64], decimals=1)
array([0.4,  1.6])
```

Comment: This works for case where the number would have rounded down, but I need to round down no matter what, so this wouldn't work correctly for 1.65,  for example, and I actually need to round to zero decimals.

Comment: So you are saying that when you round on `1.65` and then you are expecting `1.00` correct?